# Get a row value from a data frame corresponding to another column in a second data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. [The first df-df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOs6O.png)

and the second one is [The second df-df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq5Wc.png)

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'0': [2446, 2446,2445], '1': [2447, 2447, 2446],'2':[3537,177,3535],'3':[177,17,2903]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d={'PART_NO': ['KH661-10059','KH661-10057', 'KH661-10058'], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [2447, 2446, 2445]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to get the part number corresponding to the encoded part which I can get like this :

```
df2[df2['PART_NO_ENCODED'].isin([789,1023,569])]
```

However my question is I do not want to hardcode the values I want to pick up each column from the `df1` and get the corresponding encoded parts from `df2`. How can I do this?

Comment: I added the code too for getting the same df @jpp

Comment: Excellent edit, give me a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to map column names from `df1` to slices of `df2`. A dictionary comprehension is one way.

```
res = {col: df2[df2['PART_NO_ENCODED'].isin(df1[col])] for col in df1}

print(res['0'])

       PART_NO  PART_NO_ENCODED
1  KH661-10057             2446
2  KH661-10058             2445
```

For example, `res['1']` will extract the slice of `df2` where `PART_NO_ENCODED` is found in `df1['1']`. With the example data provided, this will be an empty dataframe.

Comment: I get key error when I try this. I do not understand why. it works for the given example but the actual data frames it gives key error. This may be because of the dimensions because originally df1 is 3 rows 3686 columns and df 2 is 1353379 rows × 2 columns @jpp

Comment: @sayo, So, unfortunately, I can't help with the limited information. I'm working off the example you gave.